# How to see a list of transactions on the Future queue

Tags: polkadot, mempool

According to [this documentation](https://docs.substrate.io/v3/concepts/tx-pool/), the mempool can add transactions to the `future queue`. Is there a way to see this list programmatically (via rpc, api...) or manually (polkadotJs)? And do we know how long these transactions stay there and if there is a way to flush them?

**Edit**

To experiment, I sent a remark transaction with a higher nonce and examined the `pending transactions`:

```
let tx = await api.tx.system.remark(`Future queue test: ${senderNonce}`);
await tx.signAsync(sender, { nonce: senderNonce + 1, tip: 0, era: 64 });
await tx.send();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can retrieve the pending transactions for any RPC node via the [author_pendingExtrinsics](https://polkadot.js.org/docs/substrate/rpc#pendingextrinsics-vecextrinsic) call.

So your options are -

- curl it (it will return the encoded extrinsics)
- via JS or Python or any other APIs, just call the RPC and it will return the decoded versions
- the information is visible in the polkadot-js apps UI as well via Explorer -> Node info

Comment: Thank you for the reply, but that endpoint only shows pending transactions not ones stored on the future queue. I did a simple experiment of sending a `remark` transaction with a higher sender nonce and none of those showed me the `future queue transaction` while i can see short lived pending transactions.

Comment: I can also see that after 64 blocks (mortality), these future transactions are removed, but I can't seem to find a way to "see" them in the meantime.